# layerGroup in layerControl is radio. want checkbox

Tags: leaflet

if I add "baseMaps" to my layer control, "huts" is actually a checkbox. But I only have one basemap, so I dont need that in my layer controls. But I still wanted to be able tu turn off my "huts" overlay. But as soon as I remove "baseMaps" "huts" becomes a radio button and cannot be turned off. Is there a way?

```js
var huts = L.layerGroup();
    var hut00 = L.marker([0, 0]).bindPopup('This is <b>HTML</b>content').addTo(huts);

    bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(new L.LatLng(90, -180), new L.LatLng(-90, 180));

    var baseMap = L.tileLayer("mapTiles/{z}_{x}_{y}.jpg", {tileSize: 512, minZoom: 1, maxZoom: 4, noWrap: true});
    var pcMap = L.map('pcMapDiv', {
            layers: [baseMap, huts],
            center: bounds.getCenter(),
        zoom: 0,
            maxBounds: bounds,
            maxBoundsViscosity: 1.0
        });
    pcMap.setView([0, 0], 0);
    var baseMaps = {
        "Plan": baseMap,
    };
    var overlays = {'Hütten': huts};

    var layerControl = L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlays).addTo(pcMap);

    var popup = L.popup();
    function onMapClick(e) {
        popup
            .setLatLng(e.latlng)
            .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
            .openOn(pcMap);
    }
    pcMap.on('click', onMapClick);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1st argument of [`L.control.layers`](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers-l-control-layers) populates the "base maps" (with radio button), while its 2nd argument populates  "overlays" (with checkboxes).

If you only want overlays, you can simply pass `null` to the 1st argument:

```js
L.control.layers(null, overlays)
```

or initialize an empty Control and [explicitly add the overlay](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers-addoverlay):

```js
var layerControl = L.control.layers().addTo(map);

layerControl.addOverlay(huts, "Hütten");
```